# Where is Android Studio Markdown support plugin preview preference?

Tags: android-studio, markdown

I want to show preview for markdown.
But it is not shown.

I am using Markdown support by JetBrains. And Android Studio 3.1

[image: Plugin]

I found IntelliJ help.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/markdown.html
[image: Jetbrains Help]

But I can not see that preference.

[image: Preference]

How can I see markdown preview?

Comment: I think this might be a problem of Android studio. After upgrading to version 3.2.1 I also face the same thing.
I have installed another Markdown plugin [Markdown navigator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rtp8F.png) but still no luck.

Comment: That happens because JavaFX isn't available in Android Studio bundled JDK: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-22618#focus=streamItem-27-3155889-0-0

Comment: I used Vladimir Schneider's [Markdown Navigator Plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7896-markdown-navigator). It is rated higher than the JetBrains one anyway and it worked for me:

Comment: I'm not sure but it *appears* that the official Markdown plugin by JetBrains is something that really works in IntelliJ IDEA only, not in Android Studio.

Comment: DO NOT USE Valdimir's plugin in Android Studio Dolphin, it will prevent from starting

Comment: related?: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/159933628?pli=1#comment7

Answer (score 153):

##### Updating JetBrains Runtime (JBR) will solve the issue.

1. Start the IDE, use Help -> Find Action, type "Choose Boot Java Runtime for the IDE" and press Enter.
2. Select the newest version **with JCEF** to install.
3. Click the OK button and wait until the file with JetBrains Runtime is downloaded and configured.
4. Restart the IDE.

How to do Video: https://youtu.be/Mtu3dUgK480

Comment: Worked for me on Android Studio Electric Eel

Comment: Worked for me in Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 2

Comment: Does not work on Android Studio Hedgehog | 2023.1.1

Comment: _Does_ work for me on Android Studio Hedgehog | 2023.1.1. I chose the latest version with JCEF, which at the time of writing this is `17.07+10-829.16-jcef`.

Comment: Doesn't work for me in android studio Hedgehog. This version of andorid studio is already bundled with latest version of Markdown and Jetbrains JCEF.

Any idea please help.

Comment: Doesn't work for Android Studio Iguana | 2023.2.1.  Let me clarify, It does show a preview page which was missing without applying this solution, but the preview page it shows is blank. Better, but still no cigar! I'm using JetBrains Markdown plugin.

Answer (score 22):

1. Go to File>Preferences>Editor>File Types then select Files Opened In AssociatedApplications and add `*.md` to the list

[image: Go to File>Preferences>Editor>File Types then select Files Opened In AssociatedApplications and add *.md to the list]

2. Reassign the wild card

[image: Reassign the wild card]

3. Do likewise for the Text file type

[image: Do likewise for the Text file type]

4. Enable the Markdown

[image: Enable the Markdown]

5. Go with Vladimir Schneider

[image: Go with Vladimir Schneider]

6. Preview like a ***bawse***!

[image: Preview like a bawse!]

**UPDATE:** As mentioned by @desgraci below. It's now a paid plugin. It doesn't even show up. It would ideally work as indicated in the updated [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/markdown.html) but some requests left in the [reviews](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7793-markdown/reviews).

Comment: I don't think this addresses the question. Only Olivia's comment on the question does

Comment: This answer doesn't address the question, but only points the reader toward another plugin. Android Studio 3.4 is still exhibiting this bug. Based on the link in Olivia's comment above, it appears that this is working "as designed". IntelliJ might be worth investigating as the markdown plugin preview works fine and offers nearly the same IDE experience. Just depends on your needs (and budget).

Comment: This opens Notepad++ for me. I want the internal editor. I already have other MD editors.

Comment: Just tested the same steps in Android Studio 3.5 and the `.md` opened in another text editor @TheRealChx101

Comment: @JoshMetcalfe was right on this one. It is a jetbrains plugin problem.

Comment: It was a bit weird experience, but eventually got the Markdown Navigator preview working in Android Studio 3.5.1 after a few iterations, following these instructions. Intermediate stages included Android Studio [being completely broken](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7HRzw.png); updating or re-installing the Markdown Navigator plugin may help if that happens.

Comment: this plugin is paid now, rendering this answer useless

Comment: please update your answer. I don't even see the plugin.

Comment: This is working great .

Answer (score 19):

I'm unable to make it work.

I suggest giving up and opening it in Visual Studio Code.

Right-click tab with your file, select Split Right.
In second instance, right-click tab again and select Open in Preview.

Now you have text and preview at the same time.

Comment: Can't give +1 because this is not the answer but this seems to be the only valid option

Comment: Well, it already helped a few people, yet I still get minus points for this :)

Comment: 100% agree. To streamline this, you can make the default editor for markdown files vscode in your OS and then set *.md files to "open in associated programs" in Android Studio

Comment: worth noting that you'll need to save the markdown to disk before you're able to see the `Open in Preview` option.

Answer (score 16):

Taken from https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/159933628?pli=1#comment7

In the Android Studio:

1. Find action (ctrl + shift + A / command + shift + A)
2. Search for Choose Boot Java Runtime for the IDE
3. Select the latest version in
   the "New:" dropdown - e.g. 11.0.12+7-b1504.27 JetBrains Runtime with
   JCEF OK Restart

Worked in: Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1 Patch 1 | Build #AI-212.5712.43.2112.8609683

Comment: This worked for me! 

Markdown is now a bundled plugin, but it wasn't working until this fix.

 (AS version Chimpunk 2021.2.1 Patch 2, Markdown plugin version bundled 212.5712.43.2112.8815526)

Comment: Works, Electric eel

Answer (score 7):

**STEP BY STEP COMPLETE SOLUTION**

This is what I did to solve this issue in my Android Studio. It's a mix of different solutions from different people. It worked for me.

**Initial State:**
It was not showing the preview for the *.md files on my Flutter project.

**Step # 1:** Ensure the installation of the [Markdown plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7793-markdown) in your Android Studio.

Go to Settings > Plugins, and then get and install the Markdown Plugin. Click in the "OK" button. You might have to restart the Android Studio IDE right after that.

[image]

**Step # 2:** Ensure that the *.md files are already associated to the Markdown files

Go to Settings > Editor > File Types, then select "Markdown" and add the *.md files to the existing one (which probably is just the *.markdown files at this point).
[image]
Press Ok after that. Restarting Android Studio might be a good idea.

**Step # 3:** Change the Boot Java Runtime for the Android Studio IDE

Go to Help > Find Action and then type:

*Choose Boot Java Runtime for the IDE*

Just click on it as soon as it show up on the search box.

[image]

Select a JetBrains Runtime with JCEF. If you are using for example by default the version 17.0.9, then select a similar version with JCEF (for example, 17.0.9+7-1000.47-jcef). DO NOT select an JCEF version greater than the current one. Press Ok after that and then you will need to restart again your Android Studio.

At this point you will probably get an error in your IDE, with popups saying something like "too many restarts of gpu process jcef" or whatever. Also you still won't be able to see the markdown preview. But don't worry, because the last step is precisely to fix all that.

**Step # 4:** Change your Android Studio Registry.

Go again to Help > Search Action and just type: *Registry*, and then select it as soon as it shows up in the search box:
[image]

Then search for the entry:

```
ide.browser.jcef.sandbox.enable
```

...and you must disable it.

[image]

Then restart your Android Studio IDE one more time.

And that's it (ufff, finally). Congratulations, now you should be seeing the previews of your *.md Markdown files.

**Final State:** We can see the preview now.

[image]

**Update:** 03/20/2024

I just updated a Dart plugin in my Android Studio IDE and I noticed that right after that I was not able to see the preview of the *.md files anymore. My solution to this was to repeat the step # 3.

Seems like every time you update something, a major plugin or even the IDE itself, then as part of the IDE updating routine, it selects again a default/stable version of the Boot Java Runtime, and removes the jcef bundled version previously selected by you. So keep that in mind. After changing it back I was able to see the preview again, so this Complete Solution still works. I will keep paying attention to this, to keep this solution as valid.

Answer (score 5):

There is another plugin which is "Markdown Navigator Enhanced" and that I tested on Android Studio 3.5.2, it enables a toolbar with some editing functions as well as the preview options.

You can Edit, preview or do both in a split window, you can even show the HTML code.

The plug-in is paid, but it has a 30-days trial that can be good for a short usage.

Comment: The problem is this is a paid plugin

Comment: @princebillyGK, Indeed, I did not notice, maybe because of the 30-days trial, or it was not paid at that time, thank you for the mention

Answer (score 3):

Download plugin first,and then you'd better do something to active it:

**Windows:** 
AndroidStudio ->File -> Editor ->Coe Style -> File Types->Markdown-> + -> *.md -> ok -> ok

**Mac:**
AndroidStudio -> Preferences -> Editor -> FileTypes -> Markdown-> + -> *.md -> ok -> ok

Then enjoy writing in md.

Comment: The same with questioner but *.md is already in the list.
I tried disabled and enabled markdown plugin, then restart Android Studio, and nothing changed.

Answer (score 2):

This is not just a JavaFX issue, which can be resolved by installing Choose Runtime plugin and choosing a different JDK. The Markdown plugin itself also references classes from IntelliJ UI, which means that even with a runtime that includes JavaFX, it still requires IntelliJ and won't work properly with Android Studio:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.intellij.ui.javafx.JavaFxHtmlPanel PluginClassLoader[org.intellij.plugins.markdown, 193.6494.42] com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader@4fa7c8ac
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:77)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 93 more
```

*It will still work with the default bundled JDK, just reduced functionality without the preview panel.*

References:

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360003498520-Mardown-plugin-doesn-t-show-preview

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544879-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under

Answer (score 1):

A little late but you can go to `Settings/Preferences -> Editor -> File Types`. Select `Markdown Language` from the list. Below, in the `Registered Patterns` section, add `*.md`, press ok, and restart Android Studio

Answer (score 1):

Elijah's answer is great, but you may have to do ↓ after his actions.

`Preferences -> Editor -> FileTypes -> Markdown-> + -> *.md`

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no good plugin for Android Studio IDE, If you have [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/download), I recommend [Markdown Preview Enhanced](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=shd101wyy.markdown-preview-enhanced) plugins.

Or if you work a lot with [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/downloads/) , you can install the [MarkdownViewerPlusPlus](https://github.com/nea/MarkdownViewerPlusPlus) plugin

Follow folowing steps for Notepad++ MarkdownViewerPlusPlus plugin setup:

1. Download **MarkdownViewerPlusPlus**, you get a `.dll` file
2. Open **notepad++** -> **plugins** -> **open plugin folder**
3. create subfolder "MarkdownViewerPlusPlus", paste your `.dll` file
4. restart **notepad++**, in **plugins** menu options now you should see **MarkdownViewer++**.

Answer (score 1):

In the Android Studio:

1. Find action (ctrl + shift + A / command + shift + A)
2. Search for Choose Boot Java Runtime for the IDE
3. Select the latest version in the "New" dropdown - e.g.:

   11.0.16.8-2043.64-jcef JetBrains Runtime with JCEF
4. OK
5. Restart

Worked in:

```
Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1
Build #AI-221.6008.13.2211.9477386, built on January 11, 2023
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this issue is to preview on VS Code

Go to `File>Preferences>Editor>File Types` then select Files `Opened In AssociatedApplications` and add *.md to the list

when you open the md file it will ask if you want to open it with your favorite file editor select vs code

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use markdown editors separately. Here are few options:

1. [MacDown](https://macdown.uranusjr.com/) for Mac
2. [Typora](https://typora.io/)
3. [GhostWriter](https://wereturtle.github.io/ghostwriter/)

Few more online editors:

1. [StackEdit](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/online-markdown-editors/#:%7E:text=1.-,StackEdit,-What%20makes%20StackEdit)
2. [Dillinger](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/online-markdown-editors/#:%7E:text=2.-,Dillinger,-Dillinger%20is%20another)
3. [Editor.md](https://pandao.github.io/editor.md/en.html)
4. [Draft](https://draftin.com/)

Answer (score 0):

File -> Editor -> File Types->Markdown-> + -> *.md -> ok

File -> Editor -> File Types -> ASSOCIATE FILE TYPES WITH ANDROID STUDIO -> select all -> ok -> yes

File -> Plugins -> Marketplace -> search "Markdown" -> install -> APPLY -> OK

Help -> Find Action -> "Choose Boot Java Runtime for the IDE" -> Select the runtime that comes with JCEF support -> OK

restart Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

In Linux you can go to the `Help` section and go to `Search action`, or you can simply use `CTRL + Shift + A`.

After that, you have to type `Choose Boot Java runtime for the IDE` and click on it. Select the latest Java runtime and restart the IDE.

[image: Search actions menu]

[image: Java runtime menu]

Now you will be able to render your `.md` files correctly.